# DQL Query fails

Tags: mysql, join, symfony1, doctrine, dql

I've got 2 tables in an MySQL DB, im using doctrine 1.2 and symfony 1.4.4

Installedbase and Spare

```
Installedbase:
ib_id
app_id
location
```

and

```
Spare:
spare_id
app_id
amount
```

Now i want to join the to tables to show how many of the app are in the spare.

e.g.

```
$q = self::createQuery("l")
->select('i.*, s.*')
->from('InstalledBase i, Spare s')
->execute();

return $q;
```

Doctrine knows there is a relation between the tables on the app_id field but i get the error

```
500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Hydrator_Exception 
"Spare" with an alias of "s" in your query does not reference the parent component it is related to.
```

yaml:
http://pastey.net/137237
I cant figure this one out, does anybody know what doctrine is complaining about?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the relevant sections from your schema, including relations.

Comment: done http://pastey.net/137237

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
->from('InstalledBase i, i.Spare s')
```

... "Spare" with an alias of "s" in your query does not reference the parent component it is related to.

Do add some further criteria to this query not to return everything from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you haven't told Doctrine that those 2 tables are related.

Comment: In my schema.yml i've added a one to many relation on the both the app_id fields, so it should know.